# How can I use PHP to accept FDF and then save as PDF on Server?

Tags: php, fdf

I have a client that has a 4 page PDF document that was created by a 3rd party software company.  It has a submit button that exports data as FDF.

The client would like me to come up with a PHP script to accept the FDF and then save it as a PDF on their server in a specific directory with a timestamp or other unique name and then have another PHP script that recurses through all stored files in that directory and makes them available to download, delete. etc.

I would assume that I could use FPDF library to accomplish this, I guess I just need some assistance to get started with determining how to identify the file or contents submitted.

any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If PDF file is already created, just upload it throgh a form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
File to upload: <input name="upfile" type="file">
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Then when PHP receives the file you move it to your directory and change the name

```
$myfilename= $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'].date('Y-M-d');
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'], '/mydir/'.$myfilename)) {
    echo "File uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file";
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response.  The PDF file is available for download on their site and when the customer fills it out they click on Submit.  I am looking to create a script that the PDF submit button sends the FDF to and then store it on the server.

Comment: My client wants to eliminate any extra work on the part of his clients since they are filling out a 5 page form to begin with.  Thanks again for the help